# how to run GPU on Mac OS Big Sur/Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to create a GPU environment in Jupyter notebook to run CNN models but have had trouble. I am on MacOS (Big Sur) and was following the instructions from: https://www.techentice.com/how-to-make-jupyter-notebook-to-run-on-gpu/

First, to create a separate GPU environment in Jupyter understand that I need CUDA toolkit. However, found out that CUDA toolkit no longer supports Mac.

Second, understand that I have to download tensor flow GPU which apparently doesn't support MAC/python 3.7.

would be grateful for any help or advice please. essentially I just want to be able to run my code on GPU as CPU is way too slow for machine learning models. is there any way around this?

Comment: Which GPU are you trying to use?

Comment: I think my computer is running on an AMD GPU, not sure if that was your question. sorry I'm still new to this!

Comment: Well the problem is that TensorFlow does not officially support AMD GPUs, only Nvidia GPUs through CUDA, it is very likely that you will not be able to use your GPU with TensorFlow (or any other DL framework), as Apple Mac's are kind of the worst and less supported platforms for Deep Learning. Note that CUDA only supports Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: For AMD GPUs, there is ROCm and some TensorFlow integration with it, but ROCm is only for Linux.

Comment: oh no :( am I stuck with using CPU for machine learning then? it literally takes a day for me to run a CNN. any other things I can try to speed things up?

Comment: You can use Colab, or get a non-Apple laptop which is probably more powerful than any MAC in the market.

Comment: sigh I feel cheated now. I was a lifelong windows user who converted to Mac because I thought OS was more conducive for programming. Does collab automatically use GPU or do I have to enable it?

Comment: OK seems I was a bit wrong, you can install Apple's TensorFlow accelerated version and it should be faster than just CPU, see https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/11/accelerating-tensorflow-performance-on-mac.html

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS 12.0 or later. You can use the tensorflow-metal plugin for macs. Even works for my M1 MacBook Air. It is running CNN training on the GPU.

https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/